# How to remove extra number in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am using **Laravel 5.5** and using rating system, after average result i am getting

`5.0000`

I just want to show only

`5`

OR

`5.0`

How is this possible in laravel?

I am using this package for rating: https://github.com/AbdullahGhanem/rating

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if the package has something built in, but you can always use PHP's function number_format http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: You can use `floor() ` of php. It will round a number down to the nearest integer.

Comment: @HirenGohel thanks floor() is working fine you can answer this than i can check to right button

Comment: Glad i could help you! I have posted my answer below, plz check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
floor()
```

It will round a number down to the nearest integer. This will only work for positive values, which is an important assumption. For negative values, you'd want to use `ceil()`, but checking the sign of the input value would be cumbersome.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this link
http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

Use:

```
 floor()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me! [use function php number_format()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp" PHP number_format() Function")